# Responsive CSS position

Tags: css, responsive-design

please help me with this https://jsfiddle.net/duonglam271/spdqL73a/
I could not position the tree and those fished

```css
.coral {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

.coral img {
  width: 80%;
}

.col-9 {
  width: 73%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 23%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 16.66%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.skill-header {
  padding-top: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.skill-level {
  padding-left: 1%;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.crab {
  width: 70%;
  margin-top: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container div-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 coral">
      <img src='https://i.imgur.com/y7ciVbe.png' />
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      <div class="col-12 skill-header">
        <h1>Skills</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 skill-level">
        <div class="col-2 ">
          <h2>Beginner</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 ">
          <h2>Familiar</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 ">
          <h2>Intermediate</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 ">
          <h2>Professional</h2>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-2 ">
        <img class="crab" src='https://i.imgur.com/UghhNt0.png' />
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 ">
        <img class="crab" src='https://i.imgur.com/UghhNt0.png' />
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 ">
        <img class="crab" src='https://i.imgur.com/UghhNt0.png' />
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**Example**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a look and this issue you are using the wrong measurement of grid system as it's work well with 12 grids

for 4  columns as it needs to be divided to col-3 each as 12 in total. you are using col-2 which is total in 8 which left col-4 in space and cause layout issue unless you need to put Horizontal alignment.

so I suggest you have look at grid layout and it will help you much understand

suggest code that I wrote and working on my side

```
 <div class="col-12 skill-level">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <h2>Beginner</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 ">
                    <h2>Familiar</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 ">
                    <h2>Intermediate</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 ">
                    <h2>Professional</h2>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Please have a look at https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Have a fun with code

Comment: no the point is the position, i wanna put col-2 because i wanna add col-4 later, even u put col-3 there, still does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries for it. I added custom font-size to h2.

```css
h2 {
  font-size:16px;
}
.coral {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

.coral img {
  width: 80%;
}

.col-9 {
  width: 73%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 23%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 16.66%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.skill-header {
  padding-top: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.skill-level {
  padding-left: 1%;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.crab {
  width: 70%;
  margin-top: 20%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
  h2 {
    font-size:11px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
  h2 {
    font-size:9
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container div-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 coral">
      <img src='https://i.imgur.com/y7ciVbe.png' />
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      <div class="col-12 skill-header">
        <h1>Skills</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 skill-level">
        <div class="col-2 ">
          <h2>Beginner</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 ">
          <h2>Familiar</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 ">
          <h2>Intermediate</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 ">
          <h2>Professional</h2>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-2 ">
        <img class="crab" src='https://i.imgur.com/UghhNt0.png' />
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 ">
        <img class="crab" src='https://i.imgur.com/UghhNt0.png' />
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 ">
        <img class="crab" src='https://i.imgur.com/UghhNt0.png' />
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```